# Emmet Snippet to Write Many Numbered Variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm writing some JS that requires a bunch of similar variables, numbered. I can do this just fine with multiple cursors etc, but since I'm using Emmet so much I wondered if there was a simple one line way of writing a list like:

`let element1, element2, element3 ...`

Is there a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to regularly have to apply numbers at the current cursor positions you can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) with a predefined setting.

```
"regexTextGen.predefined": {
    "sequantial numbers" : {
      "originalTextRegex": "(.*)",
      "generatorRegex": "{{=i+1}}"
    }
  }
```

- Place the cursors at the location needed (select all `element` and `RightArrow`)
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression**
- choose the **`sequantial numbers`** option
- `Enter` and possibly adjust the offset

If you don't define a preset you can type the expressions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get an emmet answer, an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), can do this pretty easily:

```
{                                      // put this keybinding into your keybindings.json
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "key": "alt+i",
  "args": {
    // "find": "element",              // not necessary
    "replace": "$1${matchNumber}",
    "restrictFind": "line",
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

Just put your cursor on the word that you want matched.  And then each match will be replaced by itself plus an incremented counter.

[image: increment the match number]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these examples, I was using Asuka's extension [`Insert Numbers`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Asuka.insertnumbers) and it's quite helpful especially for additional sets of variables.